# Need to display particular id onClicking a particular list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get the particular information from the item, like Id *onClicking* the list that I get, but what I am facing now is, if I pass(item.Id) as a parameter to *handleClick*, it will display all the Id from item. That's obvious.

**So how can I alter my code to get particular id on clicking particular list??**

```
handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
      alert(event);
    }


      <ul  className="w3-ul w3-card-4  w3-yellow">  {this.state.post.map((item, index)=> {
                           return (
                                <Link  to="/displaylist" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} key={index}  >
                                    <li className=" w3-hover-green w3-padding-16" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                       <img src={require('./3.jpg')} className="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right " width="60px" height="auto" />
                                          <span>{item.Firstname}</span><br/><br/>
                                    </li>
                                </Link>

                                  )}
                            )}
          </ul>
```

Comment: This is the 5ᵗʰ question in the last 24h.

Comment: Yeah I am still in learning phase so asking question is not a wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do use is:

```
handleClick(id) {
    return function(event) {
       console.log(id);
    };
}


<ul  className="w3-ul w3-card-4  w3-yellow">  {this.state.post.map((item, index)=> {
    return (
        <Link  to="/displaylist" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} key={index}  >
            <li className=" w3-hover-green w3-padding-16" onClick={this.handleClick(item.id)}>
                <img src={require('./3.jpg')} className="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right " width="60px" height="auto" />
                <span>{item.Firstname}</span><br/><br/>
            </li>
        </Link>
        )}
    )}
</ul>
```

This is what is called `partial application`, so you initialise the callbacks passing the id, which will return a function that will be executed `onClick`.